# Unable to uninstall CLI from Mac

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm apparently stuck on CLI version 8.3.21. I'm on MacOS Big Sur. I am not in a project folder. In fact, I've blown away all of my node_modules directories within my existing Angular projects. I've tried running:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm cache clean --force
```

and

```
npm uninstall -g angular/cli 
npm cache clean --force
```

When I run `ng version`, it still comes up and is fully functional:
[image]

I've checked brew list and it's not there either.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: You can locate the executable with `where ng` on Windows. Maybe you installed it with another package manager (yarn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list your globally installed packages with

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

To find out the path of an executable, you can use which

```
which ng
```

You can also look for node_modules directories with find

```
find ~ -type d -name node_modules
```

Should be enough to locate a lot stuff on *nix OS'

Comment: 'which ng' did the trick. It was located in /usr/local/bin/ng. Thank you!

Comment: Usually there are only symlinks in /usr/local/bin... But if it worked out..

Comment: So, what did you do to uninstall it?

Comment: You can check where the symlink is pointing to and follow that path and eventually clean it manually. You can also use "npm root -g" to find out the directory for global node_modules.